# (Android) GoogleApiClient show popup to select account

Tags: android, api, google-api-client

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

I don't want to let users choose their account. I just want to use my google account and password is fixed in my code and anyone using my app will use this account. Can I do that?

Comment: `Can I [have everyone] using my app [use my google account]?` I'd be surprised if that wasn't a violation of google's _terms of use_.

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for your answer.